# AngularJS - Injecting value returns unknown provider

Tags: angularjs, typescript

I am using typescript, and I have the following value:

```
export var app:ng.IModule = app || angular.module('app.common.values.authToken', []);

app.value('authToken', {authToken: ''});
```

Then, I have something similar to this code for registering my app:

```
export var app:ng.IModule = angular.module('app', [
        'ionic',
        'templates',
        'app.common.values.authToken',
        'app.common.services.user'
    ]);
```

It seems to me that I have registered my value in the first code block, and I have included it as a dependency for my app in the second.

Now, I want to access this value `{authToken: ''}` in my service. I would like to use the injector, but it keeps returning an unknown provider error:

```
var injector = angular.injector(['ng']).get('$injector');
injector.get('authToken')
```

`Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: authTokenProvider <- authToken`

How should I reference the provider, or am I going about this in the wrong way?

Comment: `$injector.get('authToken')` it should be. You are instead providing module name. However in your service you could just directly inject `authToken`.

Comment: Also `var app:ng.IModule = app || angular.module('app.common.values.authToken', [])` is useless. it will always create a new module, just create it directly.

Comment: `$injector.get('authToken')` returns the same error...Not sure what I could be missing here

Comment: The code as displayed looks fine. please replicate the issue in a small demo, you might be overwriting module etc.. etc.. your condition `var app:ng.IModule = app ||` is useless. Probably you might have defined that module the same way else where and it overwirtes the previous one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make sure to inject the module that the constant is into the `injector`.

Do something along the lines of this.

```
var injector = angular.injector(['ng','your.module.that.contains.constant']).get('$injector');
```